# Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:6006/src/stories/InputText.stories.ts in vue.js

Tags: typescript, vue.js, storybook, pinia

I tried to `npm run storybook` and I cant see my components on Storybook. I'm using vue3 with pinia, typescript and tailwind

here is the error message [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjQdT.png)

devDependencies

```
"@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.0.7",
"@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.0.7",
"@storybook/addon-links": "^7.0.7",
"@storybook/addon-mdx-gfm": "^7.0.7",
"@storybook/blocks": "^7.0.7",
"@storybook/testing-library": "^0.1.0",
"@storybook/vue3": "^7.0.7",
"@storybook/vue3-vite": "^7.0.7",
"@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.4.2",
"@types/node": "^18.15.11",
"@types/qs": "^6.9.7",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.57.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.57.0",
"@vitejs/plugin-basic-ssl": "^1.0.1",
"@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.2.0",
 "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^10.0.0",
```

in my .stories/**main.ts**

```
import type { StorybookConfig } from "@storybook/vue3-vite";
const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: ["../src/**/*.mdx", "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"],
  addons: ["@storybook/addon-links", "@storybook/addon-essentials", "@storybook/addon-interactions", "@storybook/addon-mdx-gfm"],
  core: {
    builder: '@storybook/builder-vite',
  },
  framework: {
    name: "@storybook/vue3-vite",
    options: {}
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: "tag"
  }
};
export default config;
```

in my .stories/**preview.ts**

```
import type { Preview } from "@storybook/vue3";

const preview: Preview = {
    parameters: {
        actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
        controls: {
            matchers: {
                color: /(background|color)$/i,
                date: /Date$/,
            },
        },
    },
};

export default preview;
```

I have tried  `npx storybook@latest upgrade` , nothing helped.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Including the error message in question description is better than linking to an external image of the error.